# Interview questions about string and char

Tags: c, string, char, malloc, free

I faced two questions from a company. The two questions confused me.
Can anyone help explain the reason of the answers?

1. Write the result.

   ```
   void Test(void){
     char *str = (char *) malloc(100);
     strcpy(str, “hello”);
     free(str);
     if(str != NULL){
       strcpy(str, “world”);
       printf(str);
     }
   }
   ```

   Ans: it will output "world"
2. Write the result.

   ```
   char *GetMemory(void){
     char p[] = "hello world";
     return p;
   }

   void Test(void){
     char *str = NULL;
     str = GetMemory();
     printf(str);
   }
   ```

   Ans: the output is unknown because the pointer is no valid.

Comment: 1. UB 2. UB.....

Comment: The answer given to the first question is not correct. You cannot predict anything when you preform a constraint violation.

Comment: I suggest you read about [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I had to laugh at `strcpy(str, “hello”);` followed a couple of lines later by `if(str != NULL) ...`

Comment: I would post an answer, but an unsolvable captcha is preventing me from doing so. Shame on you StackOverflow.

Comment: 1. Output is unpredictable, sometime you can see, because `free` will not set the pointer `str` to `null`, it just releases the allocated memory

2. You can return the local address if you using function pointer, It will only copy the value of local address, but it won't hold the address reference for future use.

Comment: Obviously they are trick questions to see if the programmer knows what they are doing or if they are "bug-writing programmers". Anyone who starts to mumble something along the lines of "it will output this, because..." shouldn't be hired.

Comment: I run the first program and I get segmentation fault, without any output whatsoever.

Comment: If I change `printf` to `puts`, I get segmentation fault. If I add another `puts("Hello")` call, `Hello\nworld` is printed. Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

Both results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The first is because you are using a pointer (`str`) after free'ing it (`free()` doesn't/can't set the pointer to NULL after being the block).

The second because you are using a pointer to a local variable from another function.

Comment: You haven't answered the question asked. The questioner wants to know why, in the first case, the code prints the word "world" even though it is UB.

Comment: "The questioner wants to know why ... even though it is UB" - That sounds like oxymoron (or not understanding what UB is).

Comment: The questioner was given the code fragment and told that it caused the word "world" to be printed. I verified with my C compiler (clang on OS X) and it also printed the word "world" (although I had to flush stdout after calling Test because it has no new line on the end). "Undefined behaviour" does not mean "does something random and different every time", it only means that the implementation can do whatever it likes.

Comment: @JeremyP of course, but it is not to say that even *your* implementation will always generate the code that will print `world`. This is not implementation-defined behaviour. The matter of fact is that the pointer value becomes *indeterminate*. It can be overwritten, the register can be used for something else, or anything such.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What I said was the implementation can do whatever it wants. It doesn't have to be consistent (although mine seems to be in this specific case).

Answer (score 4):

Both examples contain the same type of error, using an object after its lifetime has ended.

Doing so results in undefined behavior<sup>1</sup>. The text uses the word 'referred', which basically means accessing an object or using an identifier of said object.

What actually causes undefined behavior in both examples isn't the rule mentioned above<sup>1</sup>, but another one, which is closely related. The value of a pointer which points to an object whose lifetime has ended is indeterminate<sup>2</sup>. Reading such values causes undefined behavior. This happens in both examples.

In the first example, the lifetime of str ends at the call to free. The pointer is then used in the if statement `if(str != NULL){` which causes undefined behavior.

In the second example, the lifetime of p ends when the function returns. The returned pointer is assigned to a pointer str: `str = GetMemory();`, which causes undefined behavior.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 2)
If an object is referred to outside of its
lifetime, the behavior is undefined.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 2)
The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are classic cases of "undefined behaviour". In the first case, you are using a malloc'd piece of memory after you have freed it. In the second case, you are returning a pointer to a string whose memory is on the stack - and which will be no longer valid as soon as the return in `GetMemory` is executed.

However, "undefined behaviour" means the compiler can do anything it likes and the reality in both cases is that the compiler will most likely just let you reuse the memory.

In the first case, when you free memory, what normally happens is the block is just put on a free list to be reused later. You'll find you can `strcpy` to it but at the possible cost of corrupting `malloc`s free list. But this won't matter unless `malloc` tries to allocate new memory. Also, whatever you `strcpy` there will stay put unless `malloc` reallocates the memory to somewhere else. This is why for some implementations (possibly most implementations), the first example does actually print "world". However, if this function is part of a larger program, there will probably be an unexplained crash later.

In the second case, the memory from the string is allocated from the stack. In this case, `printf` needs stack space so it is likely to overwrite the memory containing the characters of the string. The `printf` will probably print a garbage string, but because you are passing it as the first parameter, it'll try to substitute any format specifiers it finds in the garbage string. So you might get garbage, or you might get a crash.

Comment: No, in both cases the value of `str` is indeterminate; even the `str == NULL` will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You did not read my answer fully. Undefined behaviour does not mean completely unpredictable behaviour for any particular implementation. Try running the first example with  your compiler (you'll need to ensure stdout is flushed after calling `Test`) and it will most likely print "world".

Comment: @JeremyP incorrect. The C standard says that the pointer becomes indeterminate after `free(ptr)`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I guarantee you that any modern compiler you dig out will leave the pointer passed to `free` completely unchanged. I'd also be pretty confident that dereferencing the pointer straight after the free will return what was there before and that writing a new string and dereferencing it straight away will most likely work too. I even tried it and got the same result as the questioner.

Comment: "Undefined behaviour does not mean completely unpredictable behaviour for any particular implementation." - correct. What it means is that ISO C standard impose any specific requirements on such programs. The 2nd and 3rd paragraph of your answer is entirely based on how a particular implementation/platform might handle this (without telling which implementation) and there's no guarantee all implementation do that way or even the same implementation is *required* to do that way.

Comment: @usr "The 2nd and 3rd paragraph of your answer is entirely based on how a particular implementation/platform might handle this" Bingo! That is exactly the point. This question is all about how a particular implementation handles this situation. Actually I would argue it is about how almost all implementations handle this situation.

Comment: Mine doesn't, it just crashes. GCC 6.3.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @JeremyP please read and understand this: http://trust-in-soft.com/dangling-pointer-indeterminate/

Comment: @JeremyP You are correct, given additional assumption of modern machines. However the question doesn't provide that context and neither does your answer. Reading it bluntly is seems as you are arguing that undefined behavior is somewhat predicable in C, which is absolutely not the case. I suggest you explain in what contexts is that correct.